Online docs has incorrect JVM flag unsafe_aggressive_sstable_expiration for TimeWindowCompactionStrategy
I was installing the unsafe_aggressive_sstable_expiration and found out that there is a mistake in the documentation. The documentation told us that we needed to enable in the jvm -Dcassandra.unsafe_aggressive_sstable_expiration=true, while we actually needed to use -Dcassandra.**allow_**unsafe_aggressive_sstable_expiration=true. I think it is important that this gets fixed because this can led the users to some time loss until they find out the issue.
Adding to that, it would be great if you could add some documentation on the procedure to install these tags. For instance, we did not know if these tags needed to be in the cassandra.yaml file or if they had to be in the env-sh file. It was in the second that they needed to be installed, and this led us to some time loss as well.
Thanks for your attention

There's actually an "Edit" button on the Cassandra documentation page, where you can suggest a correction, instead writing this on a random site.

Thanks for bringing this up. The documentation on the website indeed got this wrong.
It would be fantastic if you could log a JIRA ticket so one of the contributors can fix it. For reference, the instructions for reporting issues are on the official Apache Cassandra website. Cheers!
